# Center content after opening maximized form

Tags: forms, ms-access, responsive-design, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to build responsive application with Microsoft :( Access 2010. The problem is that I can't find any working solution. Is it possible? Could you give me some VBA code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to auto center objects in a form in access 2007?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805877/how-to-auto-center-objects-in-a-form-in-access-2007)

Comment: No.  I'm looking for something  [working like this](http://www.peterssoftware.com/ss.htm).

Answer (score 0):

select all the content then look for anchor in properties -> layout and set none